# Can't see Alfresco users or manage them outside of the admin console?

Tags: content-management-system, workflow, alfresco, activiti, ecm

I'm trying to test the workflow functionality in Alfresco 4.2 Community, so I created some user accounts and sites. I logged in to a few of them and created some sites and content. For now I just wanted something simple to test workflows, I upload a document and send it to an user for review. When I try to use one of the default workflows that seems to fit that scenario I can't find my users in the select users dialog. I can find some the already existing users (Alice Beecher, Guest, Admin, Mike Jackson).

I also tried searching for them through the People search, but they are not visible there either. I've logged in and joined a test site with some of the users, and have tried to create the workflow from inside and outside the test site. Is there something that I have to enable on the users for them to be visible on searches and when creating workflows?

Comment: Accounts can be deactivated in the admin tools area. Did you verify the checkbox is unchecked for the affected users?

Comment: Maybe your search index is hosed? Can you successfully add new content and find it through a search?

Comment: All accounts are active except for default accounts (abeecher and mjackson). They still show up in searches however. I think it might the index, as you mention Jeff. I hadn't tested with content, but it seems it's not working there either (for new content). I noticed something weird with the indexing some time ago, but as I was using CMIS, I used a workaround. Seems it was broken back then. Any way to rebuild it, diagnose the problem?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try rebuilding your search index. If you are using SOLR (the default if you installed 4.x from the binary installer) you can rebuild your index as described in [this link](http://deepak-keswani.blogspot.com/2012/07/how-to-rebuild-solr-indexes-in-alfresco.html).

If you are using Lucene (the default if you installed manually by deploying the alfresco and share WARs) then shutdown the server, edit alfresco-global.properties, and set index.recovery.mode=FULL. Now restart the server and wait for the index to rebuild. After restarting, don't forget to remove the index.recovery.mode setting or change it to AUTO.

Comment: Thanks, it seems to be working now. Is there anyway to query Solr about the status of its index? I found this in the [documentation](http://docs.alfresco.com/4.1/concepts/solr-index-fix.html), but I get the error: "HTTP Status 401 - No client certificate chain in this request".